# Flutter: Update data automatically

Tags: database, flutter, http, provider

I have a screen that shows user data and by the way in that screen user can change data, I receive data from server but when I change data it does not change in screen. I tried using provider but it send too much request to server and caused 429 error from server what should I do? Please help me. Thanks in advance

Here is my code that receive data from server with provider:

```
 @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    userCv = Provider.of<GeneralUserInfoProvider>(context)
        .loadUserCv();
    userExperiences =
        Provider.of<GeneralUserInfoProvider>(context)
            .loadUserExperience();
    userEducations =
        Provider.of<GeneralUserInfoProvider>(context)
            .loadUserEducation();
    userSkills = Provider.of<GeneralUserInfoProvider>(context)
        .loadUserSkill();
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

Comment: Move these requests to init method?

Comment: if I move to init method it take error

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass listen parameter with the value, false in your provider. It will look like this:

```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    userCv = Provider.of<GeneralUserInfoProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .loadUserCv();
    userExperiences =
        Provider.of<GeneralUserInfoProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .loadUserExperience();
    userEducations =
        Provider.of<GeneralUserInfoProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .loadUserEducation();
    userSkills = Provider.of<GeneralUserInfoProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .loadUserSkill();

    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

Comment: it does not work bro, again send too much request to server and cause 429 error.